# Azure kubernetes servive valida los manejadores de comandos

Tags: azure, kubernetes, netcore

¿Alguien sabe decirme por que azure kubernetes service cuando desplega valida mis manejadores de mis comandos?

En mi local funciona bien, y hasta ahora el despliegue en AKS me iba bien, pero ahora he añadido una nueva region en mi solucion que se desplega en un AKS propio para esa region.

Por lo tanto he elimado los settings en el azure app configuration de esa region.

El problema es que esta intentando obtener settings que no existen en el app configuration,
porque yo los elimine (en esa region no se va usar los controladores que llaman a esos commandos donde se usan esas settings)

El error que recibo es:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
> descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[myCommand,mymodel]
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: myCommandHandler': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'myHelper' while attempting to activate
> 'myCommandHandler'.

Al darse este error el despliegue falla  y me tira abajo el pod.

Comment: que es esto: `myCommandHandler` y esto type `'myHelper'` ?

Comment: creo que haca lo solucionan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029685/17161735

Comment: myCommandHandler  es el manejador de comando(es una solucion con arquitectura CQRS), myHelper es una clase que se usa dentro de myCommand. Los nombre reales no son esos, los he renombrado por confidecialidad

Comment: ha ok bueno faltan datos.

Comment: El error que muestras es más de código que propio de Kubernetes, si no cargas los settings para el nuevo ambiente deberías también verificar que el servicio no caiga por la falta de estos a nivel de código.

Comment: Deoxyseia, tienes razon era eso gracias!